# How can I use my TP-LINK TL-WN7200ND?

Tags: wireless, drivers, input-devices, ralink

I purchased a USB wireless adapter TP-LINK TL-WN7200ND, which uses a Ralink RT3070 chipset. Right now I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

It detects the adapter as Ralink, but when I try to use it, it doesn't let me and forces me to use the wireless integrated on the laptop, so I think it's because of the drivers.

Comment: Please, tell us if the answer has been useful for you. And feel free to [edit](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/830/62483) it with any suggestion that you think necessary. Also, you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/62483) so it remains as *answered*.

Answer (score 2):

## For Ubuntu 10.04 and below

1. You have to know the ID of your device, so enter the command `lsusb` in a terminal. It will show you a list like [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5582964/), remember the ID number (e.g. `083a:a701`). *You can unplug/plug until see the correct one.*
2. **Unplug the adapter!**
3. In the terminal enter the following command:

   `echo 'install rt2870sta modprobe --ignore-install rt2870sta ; /bin/echo "XXXX YYYY" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2870/new_id' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt2870sta.conf`

   Replace XXXX with the values before the colon `:` and YYYY with the values after it, respectively. And **don't modify anything there**, because the `rt2870sta` chip will work for you.
4. Enter the followings commands:

   `sudo modprobe -rf rt2870sta`
   `sudo modprobe rt2870sta`
   `dmesg | egrep 'rt28|usb|Phy'`
5. **Connect the adapter** and done

Now it should be working, if you enter `iwconfig` you should see something like [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5583002/)

If you have problems restarting the system, edit the file `/etc/rc.local` with `sudo gedit /etc/rc.local` and add `modprobe rt2870sta` before the last line (`exit 0`).

---

**NOTE**: this guide was published by *JJ* in this [thread](http://tutorialesapocrifos.blogspot.com.ar/2010/04/wireless-instalar-drivers-rt2870-y.html). As I didn't test, *I do not give any guarantee of its operation.*

Comment: The driver rt2870sta is not present in 12.10. This technique will not work.

Comment: @chili555 Do you know if this could work in newer versions than Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: I believe it will work up to 11.10. If this command returns output, then yes: modinfo rt2870sta

Comment: @chili555 Oh, could you add the information that you know into the answer? It is a [CW post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740) :-)

Answer (score 2):

In order for Network Manager to use the USB device, find out what the driver is for your internal and blacklist it. Learn the driver with:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

For example,on my machine, I see:

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Advanced-N 6200
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   <snip> driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.5.0-25-generic firmware=9.221.4.1     <snip>
```

So, if I wanted to disable my internal, I'd blacklist iwlwifi.

```
sudo su
echo "blacklist iwlwifi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r iwlwifi
exit
```

Then the USB, using the built-in driver rt2800usb, should work fine.

Of course, if the internal is not working as expected, we could troubleshoot it.